# json.decode not working as intendend in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So, I'm doing a mandatory internship, that the objective is doing an app. We save some data locally in a json file. The error occurs in the main.dart, where I need to retrieve some data from the Json.

The following line of code is returning an error:

```dart
User user = User.fromJson(json.decode(jsonString));
```

the error:

E/flutter (19199): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

the .fromJson function:

```dart
User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['crianca'] != null) {
      crianca = <Crianca>[];
      json['crianca'].forEach((v) {
        crianca!.add(new Crianca.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
```

Deleting the app solves the error for like, the 5 first times that I initialize it, but the error always come back. I didn't find any solution for it.

Edit:
the data of the json:

```
{
  "crianca": [
    {
      "nome_crianca": " ",
      "data_nascimento": " ",
      "nome_responsavel": " ",
      "consultas": [
        {
          "nome_medico": " ",
          "data_consulta": " ",
          "local_de_atendimento": " ",
          "nome_hospital": " ",
          "detalhes_consulta": " ",
          "data_prox_consulta": " ",
          "foto": " "
        }
      ],
      "eventos": [
        {
          "data": " ",
          "nome_acontecimento": " ",
          "detalhes": " "
        }
      ],
      "sorriso": [
        {
          "data": " ",
          "idade": " ",
          "foto": " "
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the Crianca.fromJson function:

```dart
Crianca.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    nomeCrianca = json['nome_crianca'];
    dataNascimento = json['data_nascimento'];
    nomeResponsavel = json['nome_responsavel'];
    if (json['consultas'] != null) {
      consultas = <Consultas>[];
      json['consultas'].forEach((v) {
        consultas!.add(new Consultas.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['eventos'] != null) {
      eventos = <Eventos>[];
      json['eventos'].forEach((v) {
        eventos!.add(new Eventos.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['sorriso'] != null) {
      sorriso = <Sorriso>[];
      json['sorriso'].forEach((v) {
        sorriso!.add(new Sorriso.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: are this data are stored in .json file inside asset folder?

Comment: What is the value of `jsonString`?

Comment: @RohanJariwala No, the .json is not inside the asset folder.

Comment: @jamesdlin the data of the .json as a string, json.decode transforms a String into a Map<String, dynamic>.

Comment: @EnzoBragaeFranco I'm asking what the content of `jsonString` is.  It sounds like it's a string like `"stuff"` (including the surrounding quotes) so that when it's decoded by `json.decode`,  you get back another `String`, which you then try to pass to `User.fromJson` which expects a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you are returning a `User` from `User.fromJson()` and it would help if we could know what your JSON data look like and the code for `Crianca.fromJson()`. Also, have you tried the code below?

```
final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString) as Map;
User user = User.fromJson(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Weird that the function actually doesn't returns a User, because it actually works pretty well. The error appeared just yesterday, and I've been using the function for 3 or more months. I will edit the post to include the data of the .json and Crianca.fromJson().